# Why the result of same squish test suite are different between running locally and running via Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, graphical-user-interface

Now I'm deploying the auto-test frame for my company, 
I have several squish Test Suites and Jenkins jobs for these tests. 
Some of our suites runs well without RDP, but some suites only have expected result while I have a RDP connection, 
once I tried to run these suites without RDP, the result would be very strange, 
the squish log said some element can not be found. And some of the screenshots would be failure. 
Have anyone ever met this situation or give me some possible reason? Thank you in advance~